# JavaScript RegExp - the "." is "cutting" the letter after it (highlight search result)

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs, highlight, search-regex

I have this piece of `code` :

```
 getText: function(record) {
     var inSearch = Ext.getCmp("incidentsFilters__search").value;
     var replaceWith = '<span class="search-results-colored-text" >'+inSearch+'</span>';
     var record = record.text.join(', '); 

     record = record.replace(new RegExp(inSearch,"g"), replaceWith);

     return record;
}
```

When I search `" .e "` , it returns something like this : 
[image]

It should return something like this (it works ok when I search `".exe"`) 
[image]

I think I should add something to my `RegExp`, can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to escape the `.` as it matches any char. Here is a simplified version.

```
var myFile = 'myFile.exe'

myFile.match(/.e/g) // matches [ 'le', '.e', 'xe' ]
myFile.match(/\.e/g) // matches [ '.e' ]
```

You should add `.replace('.', '\.')` to the search value.